# circular wheel type scrolling menu in android

Tags: android

I want to implement same menu in my application. i tried many Demo examples of wheel type that use a static image which is upl![enter image description here][1]oaded once without any success. . so any one please help me out

A menu exact similar to this

link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072692/a-circular-layout-with-scrollable-contents-in-it

Comment: Duplicate of [the question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072692/a-circular-layout-with-scrollable-contents-in-it).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a scrolling feature but I have seen some menus that are similar to the one in the link that you posted. Links:

1.) [daCapricorn's custom view called: ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu).

2.) [anupcowkur's android wheel](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu).

3.) [R4md4c's android rotary wheel view](https://github.com/R4md4c/AndroidRotaryWheelView).

4.) [lib4's rotate wheel](https://github.com/lib4/RotateWheelAndroid_lib4).

I hope these can help.

Comment: hey cking . . i tried these already but not able to reach the ultimate menu that i posted. . can you suggest me to get this done. .
thanks in advance